# Should the site's name be changed to cycling.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

'Cycling' will be more inclusive to other activities that are sufficiently closely related to 'bicycles' and/or 'bicycling' but are often considered distinct, e.g. unicycling, tricycles, quadracycles, different kinds of scooters.

Comment: Good to see you've checked things out for ... 17 days before making a radical change suggestion :-)

Comment: Cycle and Cycling are generic terms with many meanings other than Bicycle related. Cycling would generate more Google hits - but always from people after bicycle information.

Answer (score 6):

Nah - pretty much anyone who rides something esoteric will have ridden a conventional bicycle too.

Also users find SE by search engine, and google knows us by name.

Finally, ngram suggests that bicycle is a more common word than cycle.

[image]

Perhaps a cname or some other kind of redirect would be useful, but a site rename is not.

Comment: This graph is somewhat misleading because the word "cycle" is used in many other contexts, and easily outweighs bicycle (which has only one main meaning)

Comment: I agree. If people are going to use SE, they should be able to find the closest appropriate SE for uni/tri cycling or have their questions migrated here (the number of unicylists and tricyclists are much smaller than bicyclists, so this would be relatively infrequent anyway).

Comment: A more frequently used word is NOT necessarily a logically better name.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that would include motor cycle.

Comment: Such can be clarified and redirected to https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ since they are motorized.

Comment: @qazwsx So it *can* be redirected.  Does make it a proper decision.  I *can* drive a dump truck to work.